# Spider and web - stuck at the Tee junction

Tags: spider-and-web

I am stuck at [Spider and Web](http://iplayif.com/?story=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ifarchive.org%2Fif-archive%2Fgames%2Fzcode%2FTangle.z5) and do not want to look at a complete walkthrough - I only need a hint.
I am now at the "Tee Junction" inside the complex. I hear the footsteps of guards coming. I tried to hide in the east dead-end, or in the west corridor - but they found me easily. The north door in the east dead-end is said to be "not important".  I tried to go west and then south - but then a woman saw me and pushed a buzzer. I tried to go west and northwest - but the investigator did not let me go there.

The most promising direction is south - I try to open the door and get inside, but it takes 3 moves to open, and when it is open, the guards are already there and see it, and they get me inside.

I tried to enter this Tee Junction in two different situations - with or without turning on the scan-scrambler - but it did not make a difference.

Also, after some attempts, the investigator gets anxious and calls 6 guards to look at the closet because I did something there. However, when I tried to go to the closet before that, I could not do anything there - not open/move the crates, not take the wrench with me, nothing...

Can I get a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Less spoiler-y version: When you hear the guards coming, rather than simply trying to outrun them, it would be a better idea to provide some sort of distraction in order to keep them from looking for you. The interrogator's text after you fail to avoid detection by the guards should give you a clue as to what sort of distraction you need.

More spoiler-y version:

> You need to throw your lockpick into the eastern dead-end, which will cause a noise and distract the guards from searching for you. If you fail at this, the interrogator should give you a hint by saying "No, understand, this isn't in question. The guards did not see you, not toenail or eyebrow. They heard a noise, something clattering across the floor, in the eastern dead-end corridor. That's what they investigated. That's what you're trying to explain here. Clear?"

Comment: I throw the lockpick to the east, then go west and wait, but they still come after me to the west..

Comment: Ah, I see, I have to throw it only when they are nearby